# SaltStack: What is the meaning of "'file.get_user' is not available"?

Tags: python-2.7, salt-stack

I am stuck at one point in my salt custom module creation. I am running the below salt version of master and minion on my vm's, and I am trying to call the `get_user` function to find the owner of the file using the path. The path exists but salt responds with an error message:

```
saltuser@vmSaltMaster:/$ sudo salt '*' file.get_user /etc/passwd
[sudo] password for saltuser: 
172.18.1.7:
    'file.get_user' is not available.


saltuser@vmSaltMaster:/$ salt '*' --versions-report
                  Salt: 2015.5.3
                Python: 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 17:58:13)
                Jinja2: 2.7.2
              M2Crypto: 0.21.1
        msgpack-python: 0.3.0
          msgpack-pure: Not Installed
              pycrypto: 2.6.1
               libnacl: Not Installed
                PyYAML: 3.10
                 ioflo: Not Installed
                 PyZMQ: 14.0.1
                  RAET: Not Installed
                   ZMQ: 4.0.4
                  Mako: Not Installed
               Tornado: Not Installed
 Debian source package: 2015.5.3+ds-1trusty1
```

Comment: Did you try to run `salt-call -l debug file.get_user /etc/passwd` locally on a minion to see more information in the log?

Comment: Any chance your minion is Windows? I know, I know.

Comment: I am sorry, i found out the reason for the error. I created a custom module under /srv/salt/_module with the name as file.py and ran a sync_all salt command. salt was confused between the custom module and the original salt module which comes with the package. I deleted my custom module and it is working fine.

Comment: @Kalyan - it would be best if you posted that comment as an answer (and accept that answer) if you think it can help anyone in the future or delete the question altogether if you think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that I created a custom module under `/srv/salt/_module` with the name as `file.py` and ran a `sync_all` salt command. salt was confused between the custom module and the original salt module which comes with the package. I deleted my custom module and it is working fine.